# Convertir una lista de tipo string a double

Tags: c#, string, lista, conversión-de-tipos, double

tengo un programa que realiza lo siguiente:

Ejecuta operaciones matemáticas básicas, luego de cada operación guarda a la misma con su resultado en un archivo de texto plano mediante la clase StreamWriter con el siguiente formato:

```
 wtr.WriteLine(Res + " <- " + N1 + " - " + N2);
```

Wtr es el nombre que le declare al StreamWtr. Para todas las operaciones es el mismo formato.

Ahora lo que yo debo hacer es, leer ese archivo de texto y a todo el contenido (cadenas) insertarlas en una lista y ordenar todo ese contenido de mayor a menor. Ésto ya lo he realizado de manera correcta, ya que logro recorrer el archivo con la clase StreamReader y un for donde dentro del mismo también agrego las cadenas a una lista de tipo string.

Acá mi problema y donde estoy muy estancado, al realizar el nombredelista.Sort() solo ordena basándose en el primer dígito, ejemplo si los:

```
79 <- 56 + 23
25 <- 48 - 23
132 <- 66 * 2
3 <- 66 / 22
11 <- 2 + 9
84 <- 99 - 15
92 <- 66 + 26
-192 <- 158 - 350
```

Luego me lo ordena de la siguiente manera:

```
11 <- 2 + 9
132 <- 66 * 2
-192 <- 158 - 350
25 <- 48 - 23
3 <- 66 / 22
79 <- 56 + 23
84 <- 99 - 15
92 <- 66 + 26
```

Si se observa bien, solo toma como referencia el primer dígito, bien ahora personalmente me han dicho que es al ser la lista de tipo string, lo ordena de esta manera, lo cual yo he intentado pasarla a otro tipo de lista, en este caso  y no he podido, me he hundido mas. Paso a mostrar a como tenia mi función antes de realizar la pregunta:

```
static void Resultados_May_Men()
        {
            StreamReader LsRdr = new StreamReader("Operaciones.txt"); 
            List<string> resList = new List<string>();
            List<double> resListD = new List<double>();

            for (; ; )
            {
                string n = LsRdr.ReadLine();
                if (n == null) break;

                resList.Add(n);
            }
            LsRdr.Close();

            foreach (string s in resList)
            {
                resListD.Add(Convert.ToDouble(resList));
            }
            
            resListD.Sort();

            int rgt = 0;
            while (rgt < resListD.Count)
            {
                Console.Write("\n" + resListD[rgt]);
                rgt++;
            }
        }
```

Bien como muchos me han marcado ya, en mi **foreach** yo asigno mal la conversión al utilizar la lista **[reslist]** y no el valor string de **[s]** . Resulta que hubo un momento que si utilicé ese valor, pero luego al ejecutar con F5 la consola e ingresar a esta función, me mostraba error de formato.

Lo que yo deseo realizar es:
**1-** Mostrar todo el contenido del archivo de texto ordenado de mayor a menor basándome en el **Resultado**

**2-** En lo posible mantener el formato de seguir expresando la operación que se realizó, ya que así se guarda en el archivo de texto.

Creo que ahora logre realizar la consulta mas completa, pido disculpas por lo anterior, soy nuevo y estoy aprendiendo, no se justifica pero bueno. Agradezco realmente a todos los que utilizaron su tiempo en leerme e intentar ayudarme, muchísimas gracias.

Tengan su buen dia.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/393919/edit) tu pregunta para colocar el código que tienes hasta ahora (que no sea una imagen por favor). Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: Tienes q poner Convert. ToDouble(s) ; no restList

Comment: no entendi, si tenes un array de string o tenes una cadena completa y la separas al momento de llenar los datos.

Comment: tenes que agregar como esta conformado tu archivo, porque me parece raro que ninguna solucion de la que pusimos funcione a un problema tan sencillo como este.

Comment: @RamiroBarone hola compañero, acabo de editar para intentar ser mas claro para ustedes

Answer (score 1):

No creo que lo apliques pero te doy mi respuesta como lo resolveria en una sola linea

```
var resListD = resList.Select(x=> Convert.ToDouble(x)).ToList();
```

alli estoy usando la extension `Select()` de `linq` y el `=>` es una expresion `lambda`

Comment: Hola buenas noches, gracias por tomarte un tiempo y responder. No he podido solucionarlo asi, aun me da error de formato al acceder a este bloque de codigo

Comment: Pero el error se da al compilar o al ejecutar? porque segun donde se produce es diferente la solucion

Comment: el error se me da al utilizar el F5 para ejecutar la consola e ingreso a esa función.

Comment: Entonces quiere decir que ejecuta, lo que falla son los datos, valida que ls lista que iteras tienen en todos sus items valores numeros validos. Si hay algun item vacio o que no es numerico se tendra que iterar pero validandolo en el codigo

Comment: Si, la lista como re formule en la pregunta, esta compuesta por valores numéricos (Res, N1, N2) y solo 3 signos que son una especie de flecha para indicar y luego el signo de la operación que se realizó

Answer (score 0):

#### Actualización:

Con base en la mejora en el planteamiento de tu pregunta, lo que yo haría para resolverlo es crear una clase que implemente la interface [`IComparer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/use-icomparable-icomparer#icomparer) para manejar las conversiones de la parte del string que representa el resultado y luego pasarla al método `Sort()`.

#### Clase que implementa la interface IComparer

```
public class OrdenarStringPorResultado : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string s1, string s2)
    {
        double d1;
        double d2;

        if (double.TryParse(s1.Substring(0, s1.IndexOf("<-")).Trim(), out d1) &&
        double.TryParse(s2.Substring(0, s2.IndexOf("<-")).Trim(), out d2))
        {
            // Así el orden es descendente (de mayor a menor)
            if (d1 > d2) return -1;
            if (d1 < d2) return 1;

            // Para el orden ascendente se invierte la respuesta
            // if (d1 > d2) return 1;
            // if (d1 < d2) return -1;


            // En este punto las cadenas son iguales.
            return 0;
        }

        // Si alguna de las conversiones falla, devuelve que es menor para que
        // esa cadena quede de última
        return -1;
    }
}
```

#### Forma de utilizar la nueva clase

Con esta implementación, no será necesaria la lógica relacionada con el intento de convertir la lista original en `List<double> resListD`, sólo hay que pasarle una instancia de la nueva clase al método `Sort()`.

El código modificado quedaría así:

```
static void Resultados_May_Men()
{
    StreamReader LsRdr = new StreamReader("Operaciones.txt"); 
    List<string> resList = new List<string>();

    for (; ; )
    {
        string n = LsRdr.ReadLine();
        if (n == null) break;

        resList.Add(n);
    }
    LsRdr.Close();
    
    // este es el punto de interés
    //            |
    //            V
    resList.Sort(new OrdenarStringPorResultado());

    int rgt = 0;
    while (rgt < resList.Count)
    {
        Console.Write("\n" + resList[rgt]);
        rgt++;
    }
}
```

#### Recomendaciones:

Es importante tener en cuenta que cualquier objeto que implementa la interface `IDisposable` (como el caso del `StreamReader`) debe ser descartado (Dispose) para que los recursos que utiliza sean liberados apropiadamente y así evitar fugas de memoria. [ver más](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

A partir de **C# 8** se puede utilizar el patrón de [declaración using](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using) como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
using StreamReader LsRdr = new StreamReader("Operaciones.txt"); 
string linea;
while ((linea = LsRdr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

En cualquier versión de C# se puede utilizar un bloque `using` como el ejemplo siguiente:

```
using( StreamReader LsRdr = new StreamReader("Operaciones.txt"))
{ 
    string linea;
    while ((linea = LsRdr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Utilizando cualquiera de los ejemplos anteriores, estamos garantizando que los recursos sean descartados apropiadamente.

**Uso apropiado del ciclo `for` y del ciclo `while`**

Si bien la forma como son utilizados los ciclos (loops) en el código de la pregunta pueden funcionar, me pareció extraño encontrar `for (; ; )`.

En general:

- Con el ciclo `for` podemos repetir bloques de código una cantidad conocida de veces.
- El ciclo `while` lo usamos para repetir bloques de código siempre que se cumpla una condición.

Tomando en cuenta estas recomendaciones el código de la pregunta puede escribirse de la siguiente manera:

```
static void Resultados_May_Men()
{
    // ... código omitido para mantener el foco en el área de interés

    string n;
    while((n = LsRdr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        resList.Add(n);
    }

    // ... código omitido para mantener el foco en el área de interés

    for (int rgt = 0; rgt < resListD.Count; rgt++)
    {
        Console.Write("\n" + resListD[rgt]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola buenas noches, gracias por tomarte un tiempo y responder. A nivel codigo el visual no me marca ningun error con tu manera, pero aun asi dentro de consola no me muestra nada de nada ni me da error luego.

Comment: @Kristhoper Entonces tendras que complementar tu pregunta con más código porque el problema debe estar en otra parte.

Comment: No hay mucho mas, lo anterior es acceso a archivo de texto plano con la clase streamwriter/reader de donde se lee las cadenas compuesta por (resultado -> + valor1 + operacion + valor2)
Lo cual puedo decir que está bien, ya que, lee correctamente el archivo y luego lo agrega a la lista de tipo string, el tema es que ahi tengo que convertirlo para ordenar bien de mayor a menor respecto al resultado

Comment: En este punto el resto del código es fundamental, dices que se lee un archivo y la forma como lo haces puede ser importante, Luego está la referencia a `(resultado -> + valor1 + operacion + valor2)` que no la entiendo y finalmente mencionas que algo no se muestra en la consola y es importante saber lo que haces para mostrarlo. Has recibido 4 respuestas con diferentes enfoques pero orientadas a producir el mismo resultado y si ninguna te funciona se hace evidente que: o entendimos mal el planteamiento o hay un problema en otra parte. @Kristhoper

Comment: hola compañero, perdón la demora, tuve problemas. Acabo de re editar el formato para ver si puedo ser mas claro con ustedes que intentan ayudarme

Comment: Hola @Kristhoper, ahora tu pregunta está mejor formulada, y queda clara la razón por la que no funcionan las respuestas que te dimos. Las cadenas como están no se pueden convertir porque contienen caracteres no numéricos. Solo hace falta aclarar el criterio para ordenarlas. ¿Será por la primera cifra que se encuentra a la izquierda de `<-`. Si puedes incluye en la pregunta el ejemplo del resultado que esperas obtener y así será mucho más facil visualizarlo. Tienes mi voto + por mejorar el planteamiento.

Comment: El valor que se representa a la izquierda del "<-" hace referencia al resultado, lo siguiente a la derecha, expresa la operación realizada, si fue suma, resta etc. Así se guarda en el archivo.

Comment: @Kristhoper, acabo de publicar una actualización a mi respuesta con un enfoque diferente que si funciona. Por favor déjame saber cómo te va con este enfoque

Answer (score 0):

Una opcion es aplicar el `Convert` dentro de la funcion `Select` y `OrderByDescending` para aplicar la ordenacion usando `linq`

Ejemplo:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> resListD = lista.Select(
    d => new { 
    r=System.Convert.ToDouble(d.Split('<').FirstOrDefault().Replace(" ","").Trim()),
    exp=d })
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.r)
    .Select(d=>d.exp).ToList();
```

Comment: Hola buenas noches, gracias por tomarte un tiempo y responder... Al intentar darle F5 para probar e ingresar en la opcion que debo utilizar este bloque de codigo, me da error de formato con ese metodo.

Comment: Verifica si tu lista contiene string de valores numericos.

Comment: Agrega Where(n=>double.TryParse(n, out _)) para que filtres los valores validos

Comment: @Kristhoper. he actualizado la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el programa resuelto con el resultado de muestra, utilice una lista de tipo `SortedList`, ya que automticamente ordena el resultado segun su primer parametro, y despues podes imprimir de manera facil el resultado.
Deberias agrega la lectura de archivo, ya que evite ese trabajo y solo copie tu contenido en un string.

```
public class SortedList
{
    public void Resultados_May_Men()
    {
        string text = @"79 <- 56 + 23 
                        25 < -48 - 23
                        132 < -66 * 2
                        3 < -66 / 22
                        11 < -2 + 9
                        84 < -99 - 15
                        92 < -66 + 26
                       -192 < -158 - 350";

        SortedList<int, string> resListD = new SortedList<int, string>();

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(text);

        int index = reader.ReadLine().Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            string texto = reader.ReadLine();

            if (texto != null)
            {
                int indice = texto.IndexOf("<");

                int total = Convert.ToInt32(texto.Substring(0, indice));

                resListD.Add(total, texto);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in resListD)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
-192
3
11
25
84
92
132
```